# Adding id and attributes to Form element, Volt engine and Phalcon 3

Tags: php, phalcon, volt

I was trying to add an id to form element in Phalcon using volt syntax. But never found a solution for it.

Here is how I render the form:

```
{{ form("admin/saveSettings", "method": "post") }}
```

Comment: Show us how you render the input? Your code.

Comment: **{{ form("admin/saveSettings", "method": "post") }}** this is how I add a form in my volt file. @NikolayMihaylov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simple as that:

```
{{ form("admin/saveSettings", "method": "post", "id": "form-id", "class": "css-class") }}
```

You can add more attributes by separating them with commas.

More examples of Tag Helpers can be found in **[the docs](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/volt.html#using-tag-helpers)**.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: I have not tested it yet.